# Trouble with SSIS 2008 lookup transformations

Tags: ssis, lookup

I have two lookup transformations in my package. The first one
executes fine though. The second one is a trouble maker.

I am having an error ‘Row yielded no match’, in the 2nd lookup while
loading the final table in my database. It does not reoccur in the
same rows every run. That is it gives me a different number of error
result rows every run. Even when everything is exactly (input data,
process...) the same through 2 different runs.

I re-directed the rows and checked for case- sensitivity and leading
and trailing spaces, they were all ok, but the error still exists.

I checked (the redirected rows) manually for match (random 10 out of
list), match exists, but SSIS still throws the same error.

I tried using all the three caching options (Full/Partial/No Cache)
but in vain, the same error still appears.

I am not sure why this happens. It is driving me crazy, I am at a lost
for thinking. Can you please help me know how I can fix this? Did any
of you encounter such an error while doing the earlier SSIS
executions?

Comment: I don't have an answer for you, but I'm having a similar problem. I solved mine by changing to an OLEDB Source + MergeJoin; fortunately, the datasets involved are pretty small or the performance hit would make me cry.  I'll be watching this one in case someone knows why Lookups sometimes drop rows for no discernible reason.

Answer (score 0):

I am not quite sure about your lookup processing scenario, however this row yielding problem is due to properties we are setting in the processing like.

1. How we are handling the not matched records i.e. send to no matching output or taking the default records.
2. Properties on the component when the no matching records i.e. fail the package when no match or parent package.

thanks

prav